# How would you open multiple websockets in multiple threads and run them concurrently

Tags: python, concurrency, websocket

I have this code that reads messages from Gdax, what I would like to do now is start a new thread that reads messages from another websocket from another exchange and runs concurrently. How do I do that ?

```
import websocket
from json import dumps, loads
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread

def on_message(ws, message):
    parsed_msg = loads(message)
    print(parsed_msg["product_id"], parsed_msg["price"])

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        params = {
            "type": "subscribe",
            "channels": [{"name": "ticker", "product_ids": ["BTC-USD", 
"ETH-USD"]}]
        }
        ws.send(dumps(params))
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com", on_open=on_open, 
on_message = on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
```